# Random Item From a List Using Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, list, random, conditional-statements, formula

I use the following formula to output a random item from a list, conditional on certain factors. In this example, the student names are in column A and test scores are in column B. The condition for a random student to be chosen is that his or her test scores are more than 80%:

```
{=INDEX(Database!A1:A100,SMALL(IF(Database!B1:B100>=80%,ROW(Database!A1:A100)-MIN(ROW(Database!A1:A100))+1),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(Database!B1:B100,">=80%"))))}
```

In addition to these columns, I also have level of education in column C (the options are Elementary, High School and College). How can I amend the above formula to output a random student conditional on a test score more than 80% AND a college education?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007 or later:

```
=INDEX(Database!A1:A100,SMALL(IF(Database!B1:B100>=80%,IF(Database!C1:C100="College",ROW(Database!A1:A100)-MIN(ROW(Database!A1:A100))+1)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIFS(Database!B1:B100,">=80%",Database!C1:C100,"College"))))
```

If not:

```
=INDEX(Database!A1:A100,SMALL(IF(Database!B1:B100>=80%,IF(Database!C1:C100="College",ROW(Database!A1:A100)-MIN(ROW(Database!A1:A100))+1)),RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM((Database!B1:B100>=80%)*(Database!C1:C100="College")))))
```

Both are still array formulas.

Regards

Comment: Snap! Only difference is you used two IFs and I used * to multiply. I assumed 2007 but note that RANDBETWEEN is not a native function in Excel 2007 either, you need ATP installed to use that function in 2003 or earlier versions

Comment: Indeed! And interesting re RANDBETWEEN. Can't believe that function was at one time a ground-breaking, new feature! :-)

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant RANDBETWEEN is not a native function in Excel **2003**

Comment: Ah, I see. So there would be no realistic way to achieve these results without? Or could we adapt a set-up with e.g. RAND() and INT()?

Comment: It's hard to pick from 2 answers that work equally well, but as @XOR LX's was first I'll go for that one.

Comment: Actually I think I posted my answer a whole 24 seconds earlier!!....but `XOR LX` should get the vote for a more comprehensive answer

Comment: As you say you can use `RAND` with `INT` like this: `INT(RAND()*SUM((Database!B1:B100>=80%)*(Database!C1:C100="College")))+1`

Comment: Yes, that should do it - and apologies for "stealing" your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this version

`=INDEX(Database!A1:A100,SMALL(IF((Database!B1:B100>=80%)*(Database!C1:C100="College"),ROW(Database!A1:A100)-MIN(ROW(Database!A1:A100))+1),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIFS(Database!B1:B100,">=80%",Database!C1:C100,"College"))))`

formula needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Extra criteria added to the `IF` function with `SMALL` and the same criteria added into a `COUNTIFS` function at the end (instead of `COUNTIF`)